# question about pulling in process info delphi?

Tags: delphi

As it stands I can pull the current list of processes into my Delphi application and the image name. I need to also find and pull in the file description. For example, I can do this:

```
Image name                           Description
myfile.exe
```

i can't seem to do this:

```
Image name                           Description
myfile.exe                           cool text about my file
```

How can I pull in the description also?

Comment: Your question is formatted poorly (take a look at the editing tools SO offers) but I gather from your "I can do" statement that you can get the file description.  At the end you ask how to "pull in the description", which I guess contains "cool text about my file".  Could you use terms a little more precisely?  What field are you after?

Answer (score 4):

The following code might be what you're after. It uses **GetFileVersionInfoSize** and **GetFileVersionInfo**. It returns a TStringList with the various bits of version info. You'll must likely want the **FileDescription** entry. It's based on some code [from the  Delphi section of About.com](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2001/a/bltip0701_4.htm).

```
const
  // Version Info sections as stored in Exe
  viCompanyName           = 'CompanyName';
  viFileDescription       = 'FileDescription';
  viFileVersion           = 'FileVersion';
  viInternalName          = 'InternalName';
  viLegalCopyRight        = 'LegalCopyright';
  viLegalTradeMarks       = 'LegalTradeMarks';
  viOriginalFilename      = 'OriginalFilename';
  viProductName           = 'ProductName';
  viProductVersion        = 'ProductVersion';
  viComments              = 'Comments';
  viAuthor                = 'Author';

  VersionInfoNum = 11;
  VersionInfoStr : array [1..VersionInfoNum] of String =
                  (viCompanyName,
                   viFileDescription,
                   viFileVersion,
                   viInternalName,
                   viLegalCopyRight,
                   viLegalTradeMarks,
                   viOriginalFilename,
                   viProductName,
                   viProductVersion,
                   viComments,
                   viAuthor
                   );

function GetFileVersionInformation(FileName : string; ListOut : TStrings) : boolean;
// Code based on the following from About.com / Delphi:
// http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2001/a/bltip0701_4.htm
//
// Related: http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=20&printable=1    
var
  n, Len : DWord;
  j : Integer;
  Buf : PChar;
  Value : PChar;
begin
  Result := false;    
  ListOut.Clear;      
  n := GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(FileName), n);
  if n > 0 Then
  begin
    Buf := AllocMem(n);
    try
      ListOut.Add('Size='+IntToStr(n));
      GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(FileName),0,n,Buf);
      for j:=1 To VersionInfoNum Do
      begin
        // this was originally working out the Locale ID for United States ($0409)
        // where as we want United Kingdom ($0809)
        // See notes for Chapter 22, page 978 - http://www.marcocantu.com/md4/md4update.htm
        //if VerQueryValue(Buf,PChar('StringFileInfo\040904E4\'+
        //                 InfoStr[j]),Pointer(Value),Len) then
        if VerQueryValue(Buf, PChar('StringFileInfo\080904E4\' + VersionInfoStr[j]), Pointer(Value), Len) then
        begin
          if Length(Value) > 0 Then
          begin
            ListOut.Add(VersionInfoStr[j] + '=' + Value);
          end;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      FreeMem(Buf,n);
      Result := True;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Just pass in the full file name and a TStringList to the above function, then you can just do the following to get the description:

```
Result := ListOut.Values[viFileDescription];
```

***Edit*** - Love the code formatting in the main example there, don't think it liked the \'.

Comment: ListOut should be a TStrings, and should be passed by value, not by reference. Please don't catch exceptions if you're not really going to handle them. Use a try-finally block to protect the buffer you allocate.

Comment: You're a tough chap to please, I've tweaked accordingly. Is that any better?

Comment: Also, I am grateful of your advise. Thanks!

Comment: thanks mate, i am just getting in now booting delphi up so i will give it a go but right now i must have a cup of tea, i am english and we need our tea,

Comment: No problem... but a programmer drinking tea? It's unheard of! I thought coffee was our tipple of choice ;).

Comment: @Paulk, I thought it was Jolt cola?